# Adding documents with same ID to Firestore at the same time

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, document, identification

I want to add 2 documents with the same ID to Firestore when doing the following (see code below). I want [2] to have the same document ID as [1], since both are adding the same info to different places in Firestore. Right now, [1] and [2] give me different document IDs. I want to see if it is possible for them to have the same ID. Preferably if [2] can have the same doc ID as [1]. How could I do this? Thanks

```
void _sendPost() async {
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(docX).collection('posts').add({}) [1]
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).collection('userPosts').add({}) [2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
void _sendPost() async {
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post').doc(user.uid).set({});
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({});
}
```

Comment: Hello! No worries, I was just able to find a solution. Thanks